# HybriAuth - Hybriauth Library needs the JSON PHP extension

Tags: authentication, login-script, facebook-login, hybridauthprovider

Talking about **[HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)**, I have migrated our website to a new Hosting service, but now, when the user attempts to log in with **Facebook button**, the system displays the error "**got an error! Hybriauth Library needs the JSON PHP extension**".

Could you let me know what could it be?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be by the PHP version that is 5.1.6., but I'm not sure.

Comment: ¡Confirmed! I upgraded the PHP version from 5.1.6 to 5.3.8 and the situation was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Confirmed! I upgraded the PHP version from 5.1.6 to 5.3.8 and the situation was solved.